# Why is the maximum number of non-attacking pairs of queens in the 8-queen problem?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, chessboard

In the 8-queen’s problem we want the number of attacking pairs of queens to be zero in the solution assignment of the queens.

A possible fitness function is the number of non-attacking pairs of queens that we are interested to maximize which has the maximum value $\dbinom{8}{2}$ = 28.

I'm very sorry but I can't figure out why so ... Could you help me understand it as if I was a 10 years old? I'm quity rusty on my maths (but I'm very motivated :))

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? Why the maximal number of Queen pairs is 28?

Comment: @user2661923 Yes! Exactly

Comment: Please notice how I edited your query to clarify your question.  Going forward, with your future mathSE queries, clarifications or analysis (re what work you have done) should be placed directly in the query.

Comment: Intuitively this number should be greater than 28. If you first place 8 non-attacking black queens on the board and then randomly pick two of them, you have already 28 ways to do this. Now the world would be a strange place if you could not add two white queens that are allowed to attack black ones but not each other. But if you can do that, that shows the total number is at least 29 (and likely much bigger)

Comment: @Vincent If you are adding white queens that are not allowed to attack each other, you are solving some other puzzle that's not the 8-queen puzzle. With 8 queens, you cannot have more than 28 pairs.

Comment: The last edit added a question that seems to be completely different to what was asked.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis yes, I agree

Comment: @MishaLavrov yes ! And I’m struggling to understand why it’s no more than 28

Comment: If you have 8 things, and want to choose 2 of them, there are only 28 ways to do that. In the 8 queens problem it is not possible to place more queens without making attacking pairs. With 8 queens you can place them so that every pair of them is non-attacking. There are 28 ways of choosing 2 of the 8 queens (which then form a non-attacking pair), so there are no more than 28 non-attacking pairs of queens. This assumes that you don't want any attacking pairs at all. It might be possible to place more than 8 queens and get more than 28 non-attacking pairs amongst them.

Comment: @user2661923 I have undone your edit, because it is asking a different, unrelated question.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Before I placed the edit, I made a comment that was virtually verbatim what my edit was.  I asked the OP if this is what was intended, and the OP said "yes exactly".  Did the OP change his/her mind?  I know the "8 queens" excerpt suggests otherwise, which is why I double checked with a comment, before editing.

Comment: @user2661923 The latest comment from the OP is agreeing that the question in the edit is completely different from what was asked. But I agree that if the OP said "yes exactly" in response to a comment that was deleted, then things are more confusing and I don't know what is to be done.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Okay, thanks for your effort.  I'll leave it to you.  Perhaps the OP changed his/her mind.

Comment: I think the OP didn’t understood the comment then. But he agrees with the remark of Misha Lavrov which seems to go in the right direction

Comment: @MishaLavrov I was replying to the version of the question in user2661923 now deleted comment (I don't know why it was deleted) and/or identical version of the question in the now undone edit...

Comment: @Vincent Does seem like a moving target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have $8$ queens, there are $\binom 82 = 28$ ways to choose two of them: that's the number of pairs of queens we have, total.

What is $\binom 82$, exactly? It is $\frac{8 \cdot 7}{2}$. We have $8$ ways to choose the first queen in the pair, and $7$ ways to choose the second queen, different from the first. But then we divide by $2$, because each pair of queens $\{X,Y\}$ was counted twice: taking $X$ as the first queen and $Y$ as the second, and taking $Y$ as the first queen and $X$ as the second.

Each pair of queens can either attack each other, or not. For our fitness function, we go through all $28$ pairs of queens, and add $1$ to the score if they do not attack each other.

Since there are only $28$ pairs, the maximum score we can get in this way is $28$.